# Java - Replace special character in a String

Tags: java, string, replace

I have to replace a string whit special character like this: `XY_Universit�-WWWWW-ZZZZZ` in another one like: `XY_Universita-WWWWW-ZZZZZ`.

I tryed solutions like `stringToReplace.replaceAll(".*Universit.*", "Universita");` but it replace all the string with the word ''Universita" and it isn't what i want.

Thanks in advance

F

Comment: `.*` *eagerly* matches. In any case I suspect the *real* question is really "How to map Unicode characters with accents to the English-letter equivalent?" eg. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350798/removing-accents-from-string , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String exp = "XY_Universit�-WWWWW-ZZZZZ";
        exp = exp.replaceAll("Universit[^a]", "Universita");
        System.out.println(exp);
    }
```

**Output**

```
XY_Universita-WWWWW-ZZZZZ
```